# Function won't return the value I need it to

Tags: java, function, return

I have a function where the first value in an array needs to determine an int variable that I am trying to return to the main function in order to store the result as a variable. But, after doing this, the output of the variable is always 0 (thats what I set it to in order to initialize the variable in the function), even when array[0] fits the conditions listed in the function. Here is the code...

```
    public static int findWhichLocation (int array []){
        int location = 0;
        if (array[0]>99 && array[0]<200){
            location = 1;
        }
        else if (array[0]>199 && array[0]<300){
            location = 2;
        }
        else if (array[0]>299 && array[0]<=400){
            location = 3;
        }
        else if (array[0]>399 && array[0]<500){
            location = 4;
        }
        else if (array[0]>499 && array[0]<600){
            location = 5;
        }
        return location;
    }
```

what can I do to make sure that the function returns the int that I want it to return rather than just the int I used to initialize the variable???

Edit: 
Rather than using the variable location, I just am now just returning the number and not a variable.

```
    public static int findWhichLocation (int array []){
    if (array[0]>99 && array[0]<200){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (array[0]>199 && array[0]<300){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (array[0]>299 && array[0]<=400){
        return 3;
    }
    else if (array[0]>399 && array[0]<500){
        return 4;
    }
    else if (array[0]>499 && array[0]<600){
        return 5;
    }

    }
```

But now I'm getting an error saying the method needs to return type int, but I am returning an int but I don't know why its not working. How would I do this?

Comment: show the array values

Comment: This is not a function but a method.

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Firstly, I'd refactor - instead of accessing `array[0]` ten times in the method, I'd pull that out into a local variable. Next, I'd personally remove the `location` local variable entirely - just return from the `if` statements, and return 0 at the end if none of the conditions match. Now, what is the value of `array[0]`? Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Btw `else if (... array[0]<=400)` and `else if (array[0]>399 ...)` don't make much sense together. You should avoid overlapping edges.

Comment: If one of the branches is always executed the code might be able to be replaced with `return array[0] / 100`

Answer (score 0):

I tested your method with this code and everything working fine. You should double check your arrays values.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
            int [] a = new int [4];
            a[0] = 200;
            System.out.println( findWhichLocation(a) );
    }
    public static int findWhichLocation (int array []){
        int location = 0;
        if (array[0]>99 && array[0]<200){
            location = 1;
        }
        else if (array[0]>199 && array[0]<300){
            location = 2;
        }
        else if (array[0]>299 && array[0]<=400){
            location = 3;
        }
        else if (array[0]>399 && array[0]<500){
            location = 4;
        }
        else if (array[0]>499 && array[0]<600){
            location = 5;
        }
        return location;
    }
}
```

This code outputs 2.

second code block problem is that you should provide `return 0` before method closing bracket.

```
public static int findWhichLocation (int array []){
    if (array[0]>99 && array[0]<200){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (array[0]>199 && array[0]<300){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (array[0]>299 && array[0]<=400){
        return 3;
    }
    else if (array[0]>399 && array[0]<500){
        return 4;
    }
    else if (array[0]>499 && array[0]<600){
        return 5;
    }
    // add this return
    return 0;
}
```

## Suggestion

you can do this work simply by this method:

```
public static int findWhichLocation (int array []){
    return array[0] / 100;
}
```

Comment: [Are "Your code works fine for me" answers acceptable?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277923) (just a reminder)

Comment: What do you mean ? I just compiled and run it's code and see everything working with my array.

Comment: That correct and "your code works as expected" means that OP did a bad job in either explaining the issue or posting the relevant code parts to reproduce the issue. The correct way to handle this is to leave a comment and to flag the question for closure (reason for example "why isn't my code working"). OP then later changed the question to something different (which itself isn't that good), which you've answered correctly. So you can keep the answer here, but I left the link to remind you on how to treat the initial question (i.e. flag it).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the value of array[0], which you have yet to provide, it is impossible to answer your question. In the revised version of your method, you are failing to return when the value is <100 or >=600. As noted by others, you have an error in both versions of your method, wherein you use <=400 instead of <400; assigning array[0] to a variable so you don’t have to check it multiples times will decrease the likelihood of defects such as accidentally coding the wrong index; and since you’re attempting to determine the hundreds range, it’s easier to just divide by 100. Also, the method name findByLocation doesn’t accurately describe what the method is doing.

Try:

```
public static int findHundredsIncrements(int[] array, int index, int limit) {
    int increments = 0;
    if (array != null && index >= 0 && index < array.length -1 && array[index] != null) {
        increments = array[index] / 100;
    }
    return (increments > limit) ? limit : increments;
}
```

And then invoke it with:

```
int[] array = {testValue};
int answer = findHundredsIncrements(array, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second block of code is simply missing a return after the if else ladder you have.

```
 public static int findWhichLocation (int array []){
if (array[0]>99 && array[0]<200){
    return 1;
}
else if (array[0]>199 && array[0]<300){
    return 2;
}
else if (array[0]>299 && array[0]<=400){
    return 3;
}
else if (array[0]>399 && array[0]<500){
    return 4;
}
else if (array[0]>499 && array[0]<600){
    return 5;
}
return 0; // added
}
```

You have to add this one because if all of the conditionals you have in the if else ladder are not met then the method will not return anything. That is why the error for not returning an int is showing up.